# Multi-character plot shapes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say this is my dataset:

```
> ( fake = data.frame( id=as.character(18:22), x=rnorm(5), y=rnorm(5) ) )

  id           x           y
1 18  1.93800377  0.67515777
2 19  1.28241814 -0.04164806
3 20 -1.58919444 -0.50885536
4 21 -0.08127943 -1.90003188
5 22  0.78134213  0.17693039
```

I want a scatterplot of `x` vs. `y` in which the plotting shape is the `id` variable. I tried this:

```
ggplot( data=fake, aes( x=x, y=y, shape=id) ) + geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values=as.character(fake$id)) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

It appears that only the first character of `id` is being used as a plotting shape. How can I use the entire string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to print text on a plot, use `geom_text` rather than `geom_point`

```
ggplot( data=fake, aes( x=x, y=y, label=id) ) + geom_text() + theme_bw()
```

The plotting character (shape) used by geom_point can only be a single character. For longer strings, you must use `geom_text()`.

[image]